# I need help writing a program that prints out two shapes on one line using nested loops

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

Here is what the shapes should look [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwUbN.png) :

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Diamonds {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        for (int i = 7; i > 0; i -= 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I am having trouble getting the second shape

Comment: What output do you get? Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: I don't want to actually do your classwork for you (i can't imaging this is part of an actual application), but here is one thing i can see right off the bat.  You have an outer loop with two inner loops, the first one prints spaces, the second prints asterisks and then the outer loop puts in a newline.  This is never going to work because you need to print two sets of asterisks on each line.  I suspect the correct code will have an outer loop and four inner loops.  I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In order to not spoil your fun with this problem, I will explain what you need to do without writing any code.

To get the second shape in there, you would need to add two additional nested `for` loops into each of the two "outer" loops that you already have.

Loops number three will produce a fixed number of spaces. Note that the distance between the right edge of the first shape and the left edge of the second shape is constant, so your third loops will be easy to code up.

Loops number four will loop like your first loop, but they would change places: the first inner loop from the first outer loop will be the forth inner loop in the second outer loop, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

By examining the shape on the right, we can notice that for each `N` asterisks on the line in the left shape, the right one has `10 - N`, so, taking your code and extending it, we can get:

```
public class Diamonds {
    public static final String SPACE = "        ";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");

            System.out.print(SPACE);

            for (int j = 0; j < 10 - i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        for (int i = 7; i > 0; i -= 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");

            System.out.print(SPACE);

            for (int j = 0; j < 10 - i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

And if we extract some common code:

```
public class Diamonds {
    public static final String SPACE = "        ";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
            drawLine(i);

            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        for (int i = 7; i > 0; i -= 2) {
            drawLine(i);

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    private static void drawLine(int i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print("*");

        System.out.print(SPACE);

        for (int j = 0; j < 10 - i; j++)
            System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 9; i > 0; i -= 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < 10; i += 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");

            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }

    }
```

output :

```
     *********
      *******
       *****
        ***
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReverseDiamond {

    public static void main(String[] ar) {

        int rows = 10;
        ReverseDiamond diamond = new ReverseDiamond();          

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            diamond.printLine(rows, i); 

        for(int i = rows - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            diamond.printLine(rows, i);         
    }



    private void printLine(int rows, int currRow) {

        for(int space = 1; space <= currRow; space++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        for(int star = 1; star < 2 * (rows - currRow); star++)
            System.out.print("*");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may like that :

```
public class Diamonds {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int totalStars = 9;
    int rows = 9;

    for (int r = 0,stars=-1,gap=totalStars; r < rows; r++   ) {
        stars+= (r<=rows/2) ?2:-2;
        gap=totalStars-stars;

        printChars(' ', gap);
        printChars('*', stars);
        printChars(' ', gap);
        int gap2=stars+1;
        int stars2=gap+1;
        printChars(' ', gap2);
        printChars('*', stars2);
        printChars(' ', gap2);
        System.out.println();
    }
 }

 private static void printChars(char c ,int times) {
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
 }
}
```