# Java unknown number of arguments method

Tags: java, methods, int, arguments, iunknown

How can i make a method with  a string and unknown number of intarguments?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is in your assignment.... Did you even read it?

Comment: "(String, int...)", just like it says

Comment: I guess "variable number of arguments" is more suitable than "unknown". See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165570/i-need-help-writing-a-program-that-prints-out-two-shapes-on-one-line-using-neste)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void printXXX(char c, int... ints) {
    for (int i : ints) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```